# Azure DevOps - how to share one Status Badge image for any branch on GitHub?

Tags: github, azure-devops, open-source

I run [an open source project](https://github.com/FanrayMedia/Fanray) and use Azure DevOps, I'm trying show a status badge to indicate if the build for my branch is passing or failing.

It's typical stuff and I've done it also with appveyor. But with appveyor I'm able to show **one** status badge image for all branches, master, dev, feature branches. If any of the branches the visitors happen to see fails, that same appveyor badge image is able to show the status for that branch.

I cannot seem to do this with Azure DevOps, it seems like I have to attach a branch name with the status badge image url, like this

`https://fanray.visualstudio.com/Fanray/_apis/build/status/Fanray-CI?branchName=v1.1.0-preview3`

where "v1.1.0-preview3" is the name of one of my feature branches.  If you remove the branch name and say you happen to be on preview3 branch on github, and preview3 fails the badge won't show it as failing.  If I do attach branch name to the url as shown, then I have to have an image for each branch which is not desired.

Compare this to my appveyor status badge image url

`https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/status/github/fanraymedia/fanray?svg=true`

It has no branch name attached and it shows whatever branch status you happen to be on.

How do I adjust Azure DevOps status badge URL to do the same?  Thank you.

Comment: Same issue here, have your found any solution for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is a way to do this. [This thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/status-badge-for-all-branches-latest-build/684754) has some discussion of the same issue. It wasn't supported in 2019, and it doesn't appear that this feature has been implemented since.